# Prove that if C is a complete subset of M, then C is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am sure this is a relatively simple proof, but I have really been struggling with the concepts of completeness and closed sets. 
Here are my understandings so far:

A set is closed if it contains all its limit points. Limit points are when $\forall n, x_n \in X$  and $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = x$.

A metric space is complete if every Cauchy sequence is convergent, Cauchy being that for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that if $m,n \ge N$, then $d(x_m,x_n) < \varepsilon$.

While convergent means that for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $d(x_n,L) < \varepsilon$ (converging to L)

Now I don't know if I'm blind to something obvious here, but I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_n \in C$ be a sequence converging to $x \in M$. We must show that $x \in C$. Since $x_n$ is convergent, it is Cauchy. Since it is Cauchy and $C$ is complete, it converges to a point $p \in C$. But since the metric is induced, we must have that $x_n$ converges to $p$ also as a sequence in $M$. Since limits are unique in metric spaces, we can conclude that $p=x$, and hence $x \in C$ as we wanted.

Comment: Excellent. But what do you mean by the metric is "induced"?

Comment: @Hoodtingz Just that the distance function in the subspace is the restriction. That is just to emphasize that $C$ being complete is a characteristic of $C$ itself as a metric space, so that when I say that $x_n$ converges to $p \in C$, I am talking about a sequence in $C$ converging to a point $p$ in $C$, which (technically speaking) has no contradiction with $x_n$ as a sequence in $M$ converging to $x$ and $x$ being different from $c$. The contradiction arises from the fact that $x_n$ converges to $p$ as a sequence in $M$ as well (which is straightforward), and limits are unique.